# Populate React MUI dropdown list with dynamic data from axios Get request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, drop-down-menu, material-ui

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import FormControl from "@mui/material/FormControl";
import InputLabel from "@mui/material/InputLabel";
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
import Select from "@mui/material/Select";

const DropdownList = (props) => {
  const [course, setCourse] = useState("");

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setCourse(event.target.value);
    // props.onSelectedCourse(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Box sx={{ minWidth: 120 }}>
        <FormControl fullWidth>
          <InputLabel id="inputId">Select Courses</InputLabel>
          <Select
            id="demo-simple-select"
            labelId="inputId"
            value={course}
            label="Select Courses"
            onChange={handleChange}
          >
            {props.content.df?.map((name) => {
              <MenuItem value={name.course}>{name.course}</MenuItem>;
            })}
          </Select>
        </FormControl>
      </Box>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DropdownList;
```

I am trying to display dynamic data into react MUI dropdown list. However, no data is shown in the dropdown list. The props passed to the DropdownList component is from a smart component name DropdownSmart which gets the HTTP request as shown below.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import DropdownList from "../components/dropdown/DropdownList";
import axios from "axios";

const DropdownSmart = () => {
  const [content, setContents] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:5000/getCourses").then((res) => {
      //   let a = res.data.df;
      //   setContents(a);
      console.log(res.data);
      setContents(res.data);
    });
  }, []);

  return <DropdownList content={content}></DropdownList>;
};

export default DropdownSmart;
```

The data get from the http request is in JSON format as shown below

```
{
  "df": [
    {
      "course": "Data Warehouse Fundamentals"
    },
    {
      "course": "Hadoop"
    },
    {
      "course": "Java"
    },
    {
      "course": "Linux"
    },
    {
      "course": "On-Job Project 1"
    },
    {
      "course": "On-Job Project 2"
    },
    {
      "course": "Python Basics"
    },
    {
      "course": "Python OOPS"
    },
    {
      "course": "Soft Skills Upskilling"
    }
  ]
}
```

The issue is that nothing is shown in the dropdown list. Would really appreciate it if anyone could help a newbie out here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess you should do as `setContents(res.data.df.map(d=>d.course))` and initialize state to an empty array as `const [content, setContents] = useState([]);`

Comment: oh my bad, it's already done as same with props ... sorry nvm

Comment: Have you done JSON.parse()?

Comment: I guess I found it - you have not returned anything here `*return* <MenuItem value={name.course}>{name.course}</MenuItem>;` inside the `map` 

Comment: @PeterT I have not, where should I do it? Thanks.

Comment: @KcH I return it above the div. It works when I change it to static data. For eg. Changing {props.content.df?.map((name) => {
              <MenuItem value={name.course}>{name.course}</MenuItem>;
            })} to <MenuItem>asdsf</MenuItem>

Comment: you can try inside `map` `{ return <MenuItem ..... />}` ...as its explicit return else `undefined` will be returned or just remove `{}` around and replace with `()` so it becomes implicit return ....

Comment: you don't need to use JSON.parse as you use axios. axios already done it for you. I think @KcH is right about your map part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not returning anything from inside `map` which is `explicit` return and it returns `undefined` as a result

You can read this blog - [Implicit & Explicit return in JS](https://waylonwalker.com/explicit-vs-implicit-returns-in-javascript/#:%7E:text=Often%20when%20reading%20through%20javascript,require%20an%20explicit%20return%20statement.)

```
{props.content.df?.map((name) => {
    return <MenuItem value={name.course}>{name.course}</MenuItem>; //here
 })}
```

or just do `implicit` return as below (just by removing the braces and replacing with paranthesis )

```
{props.content.df?.map((name) => (
   <MenuItem value={name.course}>{name.course}</MenuItem>;
))}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the correct answer. Sorry I am not able to upvote because I am new and I need 15 reputations to cast one but thanks a lot for your help genius :)